# What is the series expansion of $ \sqrt[x] x $?

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series, indefinite-integrals

What is the series expansion of $ \sqrt[x] x $ ? I want to find it because I want to find $ \int \sqrt[x] x dx$ but believe that the integral cannot be expressed in the form of elementary functions.

Comment: $x^{\frac{1}{x}}=x-(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^3+\frac{1}{6}(x-1)^4-\frac{3}{4}(x-1)^5+...$

Comment: You could use Taylor Series Method at $x=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier than I thought.

We can write $ x ^ \frac {1}{x} $ as:

$$ x ^ \frac {1}{x}= e ^ { \frac {ln x} {x}} $$
The expansion of $e^x$ is:
$$ e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}$$ 
Similarly the expansion of $e ^ { \frac {ln x} {x}}$ is:
$$ e ^ { \frac {ln x} {x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(\ln x)^n}{x^n.n!} $$

Comment: As long as $x>0$ then the series converges because the $e^x$ series has infinite radius of convergence. However, what you have is **not** a power series in $x$ although it **is** a series expansion.

Comment: @Somos Im really new to this stuff so I don't exactly understand what you said xD. So is this correct or not. I know im probably bugging you at this point.

Comment: If you like your asnwer, then that is fine with me.

Comment: It is nothing like that. I meant that according to you is it correct or not?

Comment: Okay, I will state it another way, By using the Taylor series expansion for $e^x$ you have written and infinite sum which converges to $x^{1/x}$ for all $x>0.$ If that is what you wanted, then you have succeeded.

Answer (score 5):

Given $\,f(x) := x^{1/x},\,$ assuming $\,x>0.\,$
Let $\,t>0,\,$ let $\,u := -\log(t),\,$ and $\, z := (x-t)/t^2.\,$ Expand $\,f(x)\,$ into a power series at $\,x=t\,$ getting
$$ \frac{f(x)}{f(t)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{z^n}{n!} =
 1 + (1+u)z + (u^2 + 2(1-t)u +(1-3t))\frac{z^2}{2!} +\dots$$
where $\,a_n\,$ is a polynomial in $\,t\,$ and $\,u\,$ of degree
$\,n\,$ in $\,u.\,$ For example,
$$ a_3 = u^3 + 3(1-2t)u^2 +3(1-5t+2t^2)u +(1-9t+11t^2).$$

Note that the choice of $\,t\,$ is arbitrary and you can let it be $\,t=1,\,$ for example, but I have not yet determined the radius of convergence which is an important detail since it determines where the expansion is valid. It **is** known that all derivatives of $f(x)$ are $0$ at $x=0$ and so the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) sums to $0$ and is not valid for $x>0.$ The plot of function $\,f(x)\,$ is:

[image]

Note also that the terms in the power series expansion of
the function $\,f(x) = \exp(\log(x)/x)\,$ all had a factor of $\,f(t)\,$ which is why I factored it out in my expansion. Verify this by finding
successive derivatives of $\,f(x)\,$ as follows.

Let $\,f(x) = \exp(g(x))\,$ where $\,g(x) = \log(x)/x.$
Let $\,d_n := \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n f(x)\,$ be the $n$-th derivative of $\,f(x)\,$ so $\,d_0 = f(x)\,$ by definition. Next $\,d_1 = f(x)\,g'(x)\,$ where
$\,g'(x) = (1 - \log(x))/x^2.\,$ Next $\,d_2 = f(x)(g'(x)^2 + g''(x)),\,$ and so on. By induction $\,d_n\,$ is a polynomial in $\,x\,$ and $\,\log(x)\,$ all divided by $\,x^{2n}.\,$

Comment: Probable a stupid question but why did you divide f(x) by f(t). Also isn't Michael Rozenberg' s answer in his comment right?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you further convert this into its series sum representation?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: For example the series sum representation of $ e ^ x = \sum_{k} ^\infty \frac {x^k}{k!} $

Comment: btw I think it is best to take t=1 for the least complicated expression

Comment: Please check if my answer below is correct

Comment: Hello. Here is an [OEIS formula](http://oeis.org/A008405) for the expansion. I need to know the radius of convergence for a related problem. Do you have any clues for the radius of convergence?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Nice catch! The [OEIS sequence A008405](https://oeis.org/A008405) is indeed "n-th derivative of x^(1/x) at x=1." but unfortunately there is no indication of the growth rate of the sequence and hence the radius of convergence of the power series. Sorry.

Comment: It was used in an answer, I can link if you want, and it seems like the radius of convergence is at about $ x\in [e^{-e}, 1.37] $. There is a formula in the OEIS, look at the formula section, which may be able to be used to find the radius of convergence numerically?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Numerical calculations suggest that $|a_n|^{1/n} \sim n$ and hence the radius of convergence is zero.

Comment: This means that the series then only converges at one single point, right? In that case, how does the series look like it very quickly converges to $\sqrt[x]x$ near x=a?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Not directly related, but it is known that asymptotic, eventually divergent series exist and are useful. For example, [DLMF 5.11.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E3) for the Gamma function involves Stirling numbers and expands Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{1/x}$$ doesn't have a series expansion around $x=0$. All derivatives are $0$ (assuming the domain $\mathbb R^+$).